# Counting the number of Alive particles

Tags: python, particles

Im working on a predator-prey model, and to get some useful information I want to extract the number of Alive particles at any given frame. However, I got the blender file sent from another person working on this. And the number of Alive boids is stuck on whatever value he had when sending the file. So for a 1000 boids 933 is Alive and whatever I do this does not change.

````
import bpy


obj  = bpy.context.object     # Active object
p_s = obj.particle_systems.active # Active particle system
print(p_s.settings.count)

AliveP = len([ 
    p for p in p_s.particles if p.alive_state == 'ALIVE' 
])

print(AliveP)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[dependency graph](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html)**.

```
import bpy

# get the object
obj = bpy.context.object

# get current dependency graph
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

# get the object as currently evaluated
e_obj = obj.evaluated_get(dg)

# get the particle system
ps = e_obj.particle_systems.active

# and count
print(len([p for p in ps.particles if p.alive_state == 'ALIVE']))
```

As said in the documentation:

> This example demonstrates access to the evaluated ID (such as object,
> material, etc.) state from an original ID. This is **needed every time**
> **one needs to access state with animation, constraints, and modifiers**
> **taken into account**.